# Class with [Serializable] attribute refuse to serialize

Tags: c#, serialization

I have class decorated with **[Serializable]** attribute. I am creating object of that class and adding to datatable. When I serialize datatable using BinarySerializer I am getting error as

> Type does not implement IXmlSerializable interface therefore can not
>   proceed with serialization.

Here is the sample code

```
[Serializable]
class PropertyData
{
  // Properties
}

class Main
{
  PropertyData obj = new PropertyData();

  dttable.Rows.Add(val1,val2,val3, obj);

  // ...

  ObjbinaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, dttable); // throws exception

}
```

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: May be you should create a `DataSet`, set [`RemotingFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.remotingformat(v=vs.110).aspx) property to [`SerializationFormat.Binary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.serializationformat(v=vs.110).aspx), add the `DataTable` to it  and serialize the `DataSet`.

Comment: Can you post a compile-able example? Small details matter and you omit too much. Are you trying to serialize some *unusual* types inside `PropertyData`?

Comment: Show how you create BinaryFormatter and DataTable object.

Comment: To increase the chance of us being able to give a meaningful answer, we need to see a [mcve], or at the very minimum the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception, if any.  E.g., what is `BinarySerializer`?  Is that actually [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx)?  If it is `BinaryFormatter`, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2009/03/31/is-it-serializable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) expects the [[Serializable]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute alright, but the exception does not seem to come from BinaryFormatter, but from [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx). The problem seems to be that the class is not public. However, your code is not clear, as you seem to be serializing a DataTable. Try to store your [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) inside a [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) and instead serialize that.

For a quick reference, please checkout [.NET Serializers](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/net-serializers)